# Print character array to file in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

I have an array of characters with about 100k entries. It seems like when in the function I 
`print *buffer` it is getting cut off prematurely. is there anything I can do to lengthen the amount of characters gdb will print to console? If not, can I print this variable to file? I tried to use the dump commands, but couldnt seem to come up with the right thing.

Comment: From your description it sounds like your array might actually be a pointer.  Did you specify a length to print when you gave that command?

Comment: Well it is passed into the function as **buffer from the calling function.

Comment: So how is GDB supposed to know how long it is?

Comment: I find it much easier to define functions in the code that perform the data dump, and just call them from gdb.  (Wrap the definitions in `#ifdef DEBUG`)

Comment: Not easier if you're debugging production code. ;-)

Comment: The `dump` command was the right solution for me. What arguments were you trying for `dump`? I've posted examples of what worked for me below.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That does not work when your target does not have a file system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(gdb) help x
Examine memory: x/FMT ADDRESS.
ADDRESS is an expression for the memory address to examine.
FMT is a repeat count followed by a format letter and a size letter.
Format letters are o(octal), x(hex), d(decimal), u(unsigned decimal),
  t(binary), f(float), a(address), i(instruction), c(char) and s(string).
Size letters are b(byte), h(halfword), w(word), g(giant, 8 bytes).
The specified number of objects of the specified size are printed
according to the format.

Defaults for format and size letters are those previously used.
Default count is 1.  Default address is following last thing printed
with this command or "print".
(gdb) x/8b array
0xbffd7670:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
(gdb) x/16b array
0xbffd7670:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd7678:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
(gdb) x/128b array
0xbffd7670:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd7678:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd7680:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd7688:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd7690:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd7698:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd76a0:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd76a8:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd76b0:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd76b8:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd76c0:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd76c8:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd76d0:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd76d8:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd76e0:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0xbffd76e8:     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
(gdb)
```

If you want the ASCII character symbols printed as well, use `x/<size>c`.

```
(gdb) set logging file ~/gdb_dump.txt
(gdb) set logging on
Copying output to /home/mminich/gdb_dump.txt.
(gdb) x/26c array
0xbfff4b20:     97 'a'  98 'b'  99 'c'  100 'd' 101 'e' 102 'f' 103 'g' 104 'h'
0xbfff4b28:     105 'i' 106 'j' 107 'k' 108 'l' 109 'm' 110 'n' 111 'o' 112 'p'
0xbfff4b30:     113 'q' 114 'r' 115 's' 116 't' 117 'u' 118 'v' 119 'w' 120 'x'
0xbfff4b38:     121 'y' 122 'z'
(gdb) set logging off
Done logging to /home/mminich/gdb_dump.txt.
(gdb)
```

BTW, I agree wholeheartedly with William Pursell's comment under your question: "I find it much easier to define functions in the code that perform the data dump, and just call them from gdb. (Wrap the definitions in #ifdef DEBUG)"

Comment: How about getting that printed to file?

Answer (score 27):

I think you want something like this:

```
(gdb) dump binary memory ~/file.bin 0x100390f4c (0x100390f4c + 940)
```

The dump command is a little awkward to use. It takes a start an an end address, and expressions that indicate what to dump (you can use `value` instead of `memory` to specify an expression, if that works for you, but sometimes I'd rather be specific.) But it appears (as I've tested above) that you can use expressions anyway, as I've specified the end address above in terms of the start address I wanted to dump, plus the amount of bytes I wanted.

You can also do something like this (pass in the expression that results in the pointer value rather than the value of the pointer itself):

```
(gdb) dump binary memory ~/file.bin buf (buf + len)
```

For more information, see the [documentation here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html).

Answer (score 3):

To print unlimited characters to the console use

```
set print elements 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally use embedded python for dumping data.For example:

```
(gdb) pi open("output_data.log","w").write(gdb.execute("print myarray@100000",to_string=True))
```